# The correct way to map a REST response to a Mono<SomeClass> using WebClient/ Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, reactive, spring-webclient

I have a controller which is asking a service to reach a service endpoint to get a list of account numbers, then reach out to another service for each account number and retrieve additional data about that account. The 'happy path' essentially looks like this:

CONTROLLER

```
@ApiOperation(value = "getRelatedAccounts")
@GetMapping(value = "/relatedaccounts")
public ResponseEntity<RelatedAccounts> getRelatedAccounts(@RequestParam String accountNumber) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(myService.getRelatedAccounts(accountNumber), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

SERVICE

```
public RelatedAccounts getRelatedAccounts(String accountNumber) {
    // blah blah, hit the endpoint and get my response of a list of account numbers in relatedAccountsList
    Flux<AccountInformation> accountInfoFlux = Flux.fromIterable(relatedAccountsList)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
        .flatMap(this::getAccountInformation)
        .ordered(Comparator.comparing(RelatedAccounts::getCorrectOrder)) // blah blah, convert from ParallelFlux to Flux
}
```

OTHER SERVICE

```
public Mono<AccountInformation> getAccountInformation(String accountNumber) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://myurl.com")
            .build();

    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .queryParam("accountNumber", accountNumber)
                    .build()
            ).retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(AccountInformation.class) // This doesn't work for us, we get a very complex object as a response and need to parse a few fields.
}
```

I've spent all day on Google and I don't see anyone else parsing the response they get back, they just magically map it directly onto a perfectly created class. We don't have that option, we need to pluck the accountName from the response body and put it in the AccountInformation object. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why cant you create that complex object as classes? In the end you still can only access some fields by mapping the complex object into the more simple one

Comment: Its also possible to exclude unneeded properties, for example ```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyMappingClass {

}
```

Comment: @Joker It's horrendously ugly, basically. The JSON is mapped like `{"content":{"accounts":[{"infoWeWant":"xxx","infoWeDontWantx20":"lotsHere","nestedArr":[{"infoWeWant":"yyy"}]}]}}` so we'd have to get tons of weirdly nested data to put into what is going to end up as a very simple object - then we'll be storing it in Mongo, so we NEED to get it formatted correctly at some point anyway. Plus we only want the first item in the accounts array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing it a pretty ugly, but extensible and effective way. In our OTHER SERVICE:

```
public Mono<AccountInformation> getAccountInformation(String accountNumber) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://myurl.com")
            .build();

    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .queryParam("accountNumber", accountNumber)
                    .build()
            ).retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class) // just get the response as a JSON string
            .map(jsonString -> {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
                // parse/ map out all your information here
                return myCustomMappedObject;
            })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to stay with `bodyToMono(AccountInformation.class)` and then map into your simple object using Monos [map](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [zip](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-java.util.function.Function-reactor.core.publisher.Mono...-).

1. Create a class which represents the complex AccountInformation, but only with the information you need (dont include fields of object you dont need).
2. Use the exact code of your other service (which returns Mono)
3. You can use `.zip` to combine your simple object with the AccountInformation object.
4. As a result you have your simple object with only the data needed from the complex object

Eg.

Other service stays the same:

```java
public Mono<AccountInformation> getAccountInformation(String accountNumber) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://myurl.com")
            .build();

    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .queryParam("accountNumber", accountNumber)
                    .build()
            ).retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(AccountInformation.class)
}
```

Create the missing class (which represents the result of the other service), skipp all fields for infos you dont need

```java
import java.util.List;

public class AccountInformation {
    private String infoYouWant;
    private List<AccountDetails> otherNestedInfoYouWant;
// getters/setters skipped for easier read
}
```

Combine your simple object with the one from the other service:

```java
        Mono<AccountInformation> accountInformation = someService.getAccountInformation("fillMeWithAccountNumber");
        Mono<SimpleObject> simpleObjectWithAccountInformation = Mono.zip(simpleObject, accountInformation).map(objects -> {
            SimpleObject simpleObject = objects.getT1();
            simpleObject.setAccountNumber(objects.getT2().getInfoYouWant());
            return simpleObject;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this is still too complex for what we need, since we'd need about 5 different wrapper classes just to get the data we need to convert the one other class, but I very much appreciate you taking the time to write this out.